# Cannot import Pytorch Dataset class written in another py file

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to make my `main.py` file concise so I wrote my `Dataset` class in another `py` file.

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence


class mydata(Dataset):
   def __init__(self, X, y):
        self.X = torch.FloatTensor(X)
        self.y = torch.FloatTensor(y)
                
   def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)
    
   def __getitem__(self, index):
        y = self.y[index]
        X = self.X[index] 
        return X,
```

When I try to import it, I got an import error.

````
ImportError: cannot import name 'mydata' from 'tools' (d:\A\Pycodes\tools.py)```
````

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is solved as `tools.py` is restricted and probably a function already existed in the environment.